# Dynamically add ICollection Items to Model while "creating" in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Found a solution, but a very ugly one, see at the bottom, can someone improve that solution?**

So I have a dummy Model like this one

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int TestModelID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And another one like this one

```
public class Collector
{
    public int CollectorID { get; set; }
    public string CollectorString { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TestModel> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to (in simple CRUD style) create a new object *Collector* and populate (later with dynamic addition of new fields, for now only one) the ICollection. 
This is my view

```
@model TestApplication.Models.Collector

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Collector</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CollectorString, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CollectorString, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CollectorString, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.MyList.ToList()[0].Name)
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyList.ToList()[0].Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And the controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Collector collector)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Collectors.Add(collector);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(collector);
}
```

This is the resulting HTML code (only relevant part I hope)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" name="[0].Name" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the `MyList` in the controller when creating is always null, why? (Yes I know Haackeds Blog entry, still can't figure out why it doesn't work)

So the problem is, that this line

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyList.ToList()[0].Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

although very recommended to use in MVC, generates this here

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" name="[0].Name" type="text" value="" />
```

which is obviously not working. How do I get razor to change `[0].Name` to `MyList[0].Name`?

**Update: **
So I found a solution, if a *hard-code* this here

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" name="MyList[0].Name" type="text" value="" />
```

The controller understands it and I don't get `null`. How to solve it using razor?

Comment: your `Collector` class should contains a constructor and to initialize the `MyList` to become `MyList = new List<TestModel>();`

Comment: @RobertStettler have you considered changing the ICollection to IList so that you can make use of the indexer. ICollection does not have an indexer property while IList does. I've provided an answer to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ICollection<T>` does not have an indexer. `IList<T>` does

```
public class Collector {
    public Collector() {
        MyList = new List<TestModel>(); 
    }
    public int CollectorID { get; set; }
    public string CollectorString { get; set; }
    public IList<TestModel> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

This would allow

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyList[0].Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

in the view to generate the desired markup

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" name="MyList[0].Name" type="text" value="" />
```

Which can also be used in a loop for multiple items

```
<div class="form-group">
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.MyList.Count; i++) {
    @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.MyList[i].Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyList.ToList()[i].Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
}
</div>
```

When returning the model from the controllers initial call, just make sure that calls to the model's collection index has an item.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create() {
    var model = new Collector();
    model.MyList.Add(new TestModel());
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your collector class to include initialization.

```
   public class Collector
   {
     public Collector() 
     {
        set MyList = new Collection<TestModel>();
     }
    public int CollectorID { get; set; }
    public string CollectorString { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TestModel> MyList { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: That code can't be built, do you mean to remove the `set`? I get the error *Type or namespace set could not be found*.  Even if, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this using razor syntax

```
<div class="form-group">
  @for(int i = 0; i < Model.MyList.Count; i++) {
      @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.MyList[i].Name, htmlAttributes: new {      @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyList[i].Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
      </div>
  }
</div>
```